# Debugging not working in My Eclipse

Tags: java, myeclipse

I am working on a web project and Debug options like 'Watch' and 'Inspect' are not working in My eclipse. In both cases it says variable cannot be resolved.

Environment

> IDE: My Eclipse Version: 8.6.1 Build id: 8.6.1-20101117
>
> OS Windows 7 Version 6.1 (Build 7600)
>
> Java SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_16-b01)

Interesting thing is these options works fine on other Web and Standalone projects

See screen for error details. Has anyone encountered such a problem? Kindly help how to resolve this

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looking at the screen-shot, it appears that execution has not yet reached the point where 'value" is declared and assigned. It looks like you're at line 35 when you took the screen-shot. Is that true?

Comment: Even if execution passed by line where I am assigning value, I still cannot watch or inspect 'value'. See updated screen shot

Comment: Can you see the other temporary variables: command, userId and serviceIds?

Comment: No I cannot inspect any variable including command, userId and serviceIds. This is weird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked the Java >> Compiler options from Windows >> Preferences menu and option of 'Add variable attribute to generated class file' was unchecked. I have enable that option and this resolves the issue. Now 'Watch' and 'Inspect' are working fine in my particular web project. See screen shot

[image]

I am not sure why this why enabling this option is necessary because in all other projects (in same workspace) debugging is working fine with this option disabled. Can anyone explain?

Answer (score -1):

The execution of your code has not reach the point where your variable "value" is instanciated. Press F6 twice (to execute the next 2 lines) and you will see your variable's value.

Comment: sorry even if i execute line where variable value is assigned a value, i am still cannot inspect or watch it. Updated screen shot.